# css not loading when change admin language

Tags: admin, css, language

After I changed the language in admin panel the **`css`** in backend didn't load. I have tried different language
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to deploy the admin theme specific for your locale which you switched to

For Example:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US -t Vendor/BackendTheme;
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy vi_VN -t Vendor/BackendTheme;
```